# How to correctly write robust async code with multiple await

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

For the code that I've got below what is the recommend way to rewrite this code to be more robust?

I'm trying to get this a better understand of await async.

If you'll notice in the code below I'm awaiting two methods in order to get one result to be added to the allSheets.

What can I do to get better performance out of the code below. I need these method calls to run all at the same time and not one after another, accept for the ones that are lined up in parallel; obviously the first method has to return a result in order to invoke the method waiting on the result.

```
async static Task<List<Bitmap>> BuildSheetsAsync(Guid userID, IElevation elevation, bool includeLabels)
            {
         var processedParts = await new PartsProcessor.PartProcessor().ProcessParts(userID, elevation, false);
            processedParts.Elevation = elevation;

          List<Bitmap> allSheets = new List<Bitmap>();
        //materials list
        allSheets.Add(await (await MaterialsList.Manager.GetMaterialListAsync(processedParts)).GetDrawingAsync());

        //optimized parts
        allSheets.Add(await (await Optimization.Manager.GetOptimizedPartsAsync(processedParts)).GetDrawingAsync());

        //cut sheet
        processedParts = await new PartsProcessor.PartProcessor().ProcessParts(userID, elevation, true);
        processedParts.Elevation = elevation;
        allSheets.Add(await CutSheet.Manager.GetCutSheet(processedParts).GetDrawingAsync());
    }
```

---

Additional question

For the case of the labels like below, it returns a List. How do I get that to work? I getting an error when I add the lbls to the allSheets.AddRange.

```
//labels
        if (includeLabels)
        {
            var lbls = GetGetLabelsDrawingAsync(processedParts);

            allSheets.AddRange(await Task.WhenAll(materialsList, optimizedParts, cutSheet, lbls));
        }
        else
        {
            allSheets.AddRange(await Task.WhenAll(materialsList, optimizedParts, cutSheet));
        }
        return allSheets;
    }
    static async Task<List<Bitmap>> GetGetLabelsDrawingAsync(ProcessedParts processedParts)
    {
        var list = await AlumCloudPlans.Manager.GetLabelsAsync(processedParts);
        return await list.GetSheets(new SheetInfo(3, 10, 240, 90, 780, 980));
    }
```

Comment: I'm a noob at `await`, so I don't get it.. why `await` when adding to a collection?

Comment: Because the amount of processing that takes place for each one of those methods. Each one of those methods builds Bitmaps and some of the processing is real intensive.

Comment: I mean adding to a collection shouldn't be that slow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just start multiple `Task`s and then use `Task.WhenAll`:

```
var materials = GetMaterialDrawingAsync(processedParts);
var optimized = GetOptimizedDrawingAsync(processedParts);
var cut = GetCutDrawingAsync(processedParts);
allSheets.AddRange(await Task.WhenAll(materials, optimized, cut));
```

Note the simplified `async` methods to remove the serial `await`s (simplifies the code a bit):

```
static async Task<Sheet> GetMaterialDrawingAsync(ProcessedParts processedParts)
{
  var list = await MaterialsList.Manager.GetMaterialListAsync(processedParts);
  return await list.GetDrawingAsync();
}
```

Comment: Since he's passing the same object to all of those tasks I sure hope he is not doing anything thread-unsafe with it.

Comment: @TrevorElliott: `async` does not necessarily mean multithreaded. But if he's using `Task.Run` or executing this without a context (i.e., on the thread pool), then yes, he'd need to consider thread safety.

Comment: I assume he's spawning multiple threads if he wants to process multiple bitmaps in parallel.

Comment: @TrevorElliott: I would agree except that most APIs for modifying bitmaps on Windows are annoyingly tied to the UI thread.

Comment: Good answer, but wondering, isn't `async await` best used for IO intensive situations not CPU? Does it matter?

Comment: @LewsTherin: `Task.WhenAll` with `Task.Run` can be used for *simple* parallel operations, but in general I agree that the TPL (`Parallel`/PLINQ) is better for parallel processing. In this case the op already had awaitable methods so `WhenAll` is the easiest way to combine them.

Comment: @LewsTherin Sort of.  You want to call I/O operations asynchronously to avoid blocking (in most cases) the UI thread.  But that's not to say you're going to get better I/O performance by reading multiple files at once instead of 1 at a time unless they happen to be on different drives for example...  Processing in parallel is more important for CPU-bound tasks since most computers have 2-4 cores.

Comment: The task scheduler might run all the tasks on the same thread or split them across multiple threads in any denomination it chooses.  It obfuscates needing to know whether you're working on a 8-core server or a single core tablet for example... you just break your code into units of work.  But you shouldn't make any assumptions about thread safety because code that works on one system at one time might not work elsewhere.

Comment: @TrevorElliott Correct. In case of async await it seems to be favored with IO processing than CPU processing, hence my question

Comment: @StephenCleary's blog is actually really good for learning a lot about async programming in C# http://blog.stephencleary.com/

Comment: I getting an error when trying to add a list List<Bitmap>. The labels or lbl as you'll see in the if clause. How do I get the lbls to work? I've updated the code above.